# Debugging Episerver Find

Tags: episerver

My Episerver Find content indexing job gets quite a few errors when I run it from the editor page, but I don't get any information about which pages/blocks/properties are causing the issue - it just says "see log for more information".

We are already logging everything Episerver and I have tried adding

```
<logger name="EPiServer.Find">
   <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
   <level value="All" />
</logger>
```

How can I debug the content indexing job?

Comment: You will miss quite a bit since you're only setting those options for a logger named "EPiServer.Find". Perhaps you could log everything to the output debug appender, and index locally while following the log through DebugView or equivalent?

Comment: I usually find (hehe) issues when hooking up Fiddler.